# Изменение размера изображения на лету при загрузке

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Нужен код, чтобы на лету изменять размер загружаемого изображения с последующей загрузкой на сайт, без загрузки оригинала, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Изменить на стороне клиента никак нельзя.

Можно сделать так:
создается iframe который отправляет картинку без перезагрузки страницы, после этого уже на сервере следующие действия:

```
$img  = fl::save_image($_FILES['my_file'], $dir, $width, $height);

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Функция сохранения изображения
    // Если передается высота или ширина то изображение ресайзится
    public static function save_image($file, $dir = UPLOAD_FILE_DIR, $width = false, $height = false, $name = '')
    {   
        @$params = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);
        if($params[2] == 1 || $params[2] == 2 || $params[2] == 3)
        {
            $data     = explode("/", $file["type"]);
            if($data[1]=='jpeg') $data[1] = 'jpg';
            if(empty($name))
                $name     = md5(time()+rand(1, 1000)).".".$data[1];
            $file_path = self::save_file($file,$dir,$name);
            if($width != false || $height != false)
                self::resize_image($file_path, $file_path, $width, $height);
        }

        return $name;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Функция обрезки изображения
    public static function resize_image($oldImage, $newImage, $newWidth = false, $newHeight = false){
        $source_src = $oldImage;
        $params = getimagesize($source_src);
        switch ( $params[2] ) {
            case 1: $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_src); break;
            case 2: $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_src); break;
            case 3: $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_src); break;
        }

        if (($newWidth != false && $params[0]>$newWidth) || ($newHeight != false && $params[1]>$newHeight)) 
        {
            if($newWidth != false) {$koef = $params[0] / $newWidth; $newHeight = floor($params[1] / $koef);}
            elseif($newHeight != false) {$koef = $params[1] / $newHeight; $newWidth = floor($params[0] / $koef);}
            $resource = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

            imagecopyresampled($resource, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            $newWidth, $newHeight, $params[0], $params[1]);

            $resource_src = $newImage;
            imagePng($resource, $resource_src);
        }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ага, проблема в том, что тут картинка ЗАГРУЖАЕТСЯ, а ОП просил без загрузки оригинала на сайт. Вероятно, в целях экономии системных ресурсов.

Comment: Я написал сразу что это невозможно требуемыми ресурсами, и описал как можно создавать иллюзию подобного действия.

Answer (score 1):

На указанных языках решение отсутствует: javascript не имеет доступа к загружаемым файлам, PHP имеет доступ только к тому, что лежит на серваке.
Решения представлены на Flash, Silverlight, ActiveX(теоретически)...

Ну, еще можно заставить пользователя изменять размер или написать свой тулбар. Но это уже совсем изврат.

**upd** на апдейт:
jquery тут не поможет, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API для доступа к изображению, а далее в canvas и отправкой на сервер уже бинарника.

```
var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
var file = event.target.files[0];
if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result;
            image.onload = function() {
            // go manipulation with image
        }
    }
}
```

Вот, что то подобное в реализации (только HTML5 и jQuery, без PHP, GD, etc.): [JQuery CropBox](http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Очень простая задача, загружаем картинку на сервер, потом меняем её размер и сохраняем, а оригинал удаляем.

Comment: без загрузки оригинала